# Run without TOmniEventMonitor

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, omnithreadlibrary

How can I run tasks without `TOmniEventMonitor`? If I start them without it the main thread freezes. Which makes no sense because `OmniThreadLibrary` is supposed to be based on `TThread`. `UnObserved` doesn't really fix this because it just makes an internal copy of the same thing.

```
type
  TWorker = class(TOmniWorker)
    function Initialize: Boolean; override;
    constructor Create;
  end;

begin
var
  Task: IOmniTaskControl;
begin
  Task := CreateTask(TWorker.Create()).Run; // blocks main thread
  Task := CreateTask(TWorker.Create()).UnObserved.Run; // will create internal monitor each time
  Task := CreateTask(TWorker.Create()).OnTerminated().Run; // will create internal monitor each time
end.
```

If I create a `TThread` it doesn't need any kind of "Monitors" and it doesn't block the main thread either. I am not sending any kind of messages so why the need for a "Monitor"?

Comment: Some code would help here...

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, you don't need a monitor. You only need a monitor if you don't save the result of CreateTask in a variable which returns an IOmniTask... I don't have Delphi open so I am typing this from memory.

Comment: Please read: http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2009/11/omnithreadlibrary-patterns-task.html

Comment: @gabr The solution was `List: TList<IOmniTaskControl>` equally `Array` would work aswell.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing exactly that thing mentioned chapter 4.4 in the book *Parallel Programming with OmniThreadLibrary* as

> The simplest example of the wrong approach can be written in one line:
>
> `CreateTask(MyWorker).Run;`

As a solution you can assign the result of CreateTask to a variable with a scope that covers the runtime of the process.

The other solution (as you found yourself) is to use a monitor.